# How to open a "-" dashed filename using terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, filenames

I tried gedit, nano, vi, leafpad and other text editors , it won't open, I tried cat and other file looking commands, and I ensure you it's a file not a directory!

[image]

Answer (score 129, accepted):

This type of approach has a lot of misunderstanding because using **-** as an argument refers to **STDIN/STDOUT** i.e **dev/stdin** or **dev/stdout** .So if you want to open this type of file you have to specify the full location of the file such as **./-** .For eg. , if you want to see what is in that file use **cat ./-**

Answer (score 31):

Both `cat < -` and `./-` command will give you the output

Answer (score 7):

you can use redirection

`cat < -file_name`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `rev` command doesn't treat `-` as a special character.

From the man page

```
The rev utility copies the specified files to standard output, reversing the order of characters in every line.
```

so
`rev - | rev`

should show what's in the file in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is `more` command i.e., `more -`

Answer (score -1):

I tried with pico or vi command.`pico readme` which allowed me open in editor and read the contents.