# (Unix) How to type file content?

Tags: unix

I have file named `-`. `cat -` means standart input, but what if I want to open file, which name is `-`? I already searched a lot of information and asked some people, but they even don't know how to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187323/how-to-open-a-dashed-filename-using-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the relative path of the file

```sh
cat ./-
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped for me. I will accept your answer 8 minutes later because of rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like:

```
cat <-
```

this explicitly will redirect the file to stdin